# confusing statement while version change

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I've the below XSLT statement.

```
 <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(
    ./title/content-style/text(),' ')" />
```

when i use the style sheet version 1 as

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
      xmlns:ntw="Number2Word.uri" 
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      exclude-result-prefixes="ntw">
```

But when i change it to version 2.0 as below.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:ntw="Number2Word.uri" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="ntw">
```

it is throwing the below error

```
XSLT 2.0 Debugging Error: Error: 
file:///C:/Users/u0138039/Desktop/Proview/HK/HKWB2014/XSLT%20and%20CSS/new_bull.xsl:202: 
Wrong occurrence to match required sequence type -   
Details: -     XPTY0004: The supplied sequence ('2' item(s)) has 
the wrong occurrence to match the sequence type xs:string ('zero or 
one')
```

please let me know what is going right in XSL1.0 is going wrong in XSL 2.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, when you pass a node set of more than one node to a function that expects a single string, it simply uses the string value of the *first* node in the set and ignores the rest of them.  In XSLT 2.0 the `substring-after` function expects its arguments to be `xs:string?`, i.e. zero or one string, so if you pass it a sequence with more than one item it will cause a type mismatch error.

I presume that `./title/content-style/text()` selects more than one node, i.e. there's more than one `title`, more than one `content-style` and/or more than one text node within the `content-style` element.

Consider whether you actually need to use `text()` here at all - do you really need to process each text node child of `content-style` individually, or do you just want the string value of the `content-style` element as a whole?  If the former, you need something like `title/content-style/text()/substring-before(., ' ')` (which only works in 2.0), if the latter, try just saying `substring-after(title/content-style, ' ')`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but for me, it turned out that while my schema, for the element in question, had the multiplicity `optional` setting, it did not have the `unbounded` setting, and the input data I was using had 2 elements where it was expecting 0...1